# How can I start the integrated pgp-agent that comes shipped with the new KDE on openSUSE 12.1?

Tags: thunderbird, opensuse, enigmail

How can I start the integrated pgp-agent in OpenSUSE 12.1?

Running OpenSUSE 12.1 with the following software installed all via YAST:

```
tbird
enigmail
pinentry
gnupg
```

as `root` (as the superuser). Can this cause some problems?

When I start tbird and click on any mail then I get the following error:

> the GPG-Agent-Aapplication for your GnuPG-Version 2.0.18 could not get  started

After struggeling with this for  a while, I thought that should try out something new.
I tried to activate the integrated KDE GPG agent.

I was guided through a tour - within the Kgp application - and finally I was able to create a new key and to integrate or better import some keys (that I have stored on a usb-stick, note those keys I saved from the old machine).

All went OK, but I still am not able to get rid of this "Agent could not be started" message.

How can I start the integrated pgp-agent that comes shipped with the new KDE?

Answer (score 1):

try `gpg-agent --daemon` :)

as written on the [KDE Forums.](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=215&t=98952)

If you want it to run on startup, so you may add it to autostart (search autostart from kickoff KDE menu, then click Add program and enter there: `gpg-agent --daemon`